# Can’t seem to pass mysql.connector module from main to a module I have imported

Tags: python, mysql

I’m in the process of trying to break rather long python script into a more easily maintained set of scripts all defined with a py extension.  The overall program reads and writes to/from a mysql database.

The login module I wrote is a function that looks like this:

```
    def login():
      print ('Entered login')
      cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user='',password='',host='',database='')
      print(cnx.user + ' is connected to the ' + cnx.database)
```

In the main program I have (among other imports like   from tkinter import *)

```
     import mysql.connector 
     import login
```

When I run the main program (using a button widget with the command=login.login, it gets to the module and prints ‘Login entered’
But, the myssl.connector is not executed.  I get a nameerror

```
      NameError: name 'mysql' is not defined
```

If I add the login function to the main program, I do not get the error message and the login proceeds. However, when I add additional modules which access mysql, the mysql connection does not exist in these new modules.

I've tried many ways.

Thanks

Comment: The message is clear, the module has no reference to `mysql`.  You have `import`ed `mysql` in *main.py*, but (i assume) not in your login module.

Comment: I thought that i had tried this which didn't work.  But, I just tried it again, and it worked.  Thanks oldboy.  I'm a real old man